# Why it ignores the second character

Tags: c, char

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char x;
    printf("Program shows your name and check if the first letter is capital");
    while (scanf_s("%c", &x) !=1 ||  getchar() !='\n')
    {
        if (islower(x))
        {
            printf("Name begins with a capital letter\n");
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                ;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", x);
        }
        break;
    }
    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%c", x);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

For example:
When I type "Matthew" the result is "Mtthew". Whats wrong? I have no clue.
I tried to change almost everything in first "while" but i think the problem is not there. Any ideas?

Comment: 3 while loops for that function? maybe you should consider re-writing it

Comment: You should declare x as an `int` if you are comparing it to EOF. Also `int main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Comment: Not sure but i think break after else must be inside the else block

Answer (score 3):

The function getChar() removes a character from the input stream, so that it is no longer upon it.  By using it within your conditional statement, it is:

- Getting the character from the stream (a.k.a: removing it)
- Comparing it, and finally
- Discarding it (without having saved it somewhere)

If you refactor your code to consider this, then I believe your mystery character will return :-)

Answer (score 0):

Change the first `while` to

```
    while ((x = getchar()) != EOF && x != '\n')
```

EDIT: And change `char x` to `int x` because `EOF` isn't guaranteed to be representable by a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program worked without skipping a character when the following changes were made:  (refer to comments in-line)

```
int x;  //change to int for use with getchar()
printf("Program shows your name and check if the first letter is capital");
while (scanf("%d", &x) !=1 ||  getchar() !='\n')
               ^ //changed to d for int
```

But the comment made in @J.Murray's answer about `getchar()` eating a character is valid.  So although your program worked for me, there are some input sequences for which it will not.

***Note***:  The reason for using `int` as opposed to `char` is that `getchar()` can return `EOF`, which == -1.  A `char` cannot contain a -1.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly incorrect use of `scanf_s("%c", &x)`

> The fscanf_s function is equivalent to fscanf except that the c, s, and [ conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments (unless assignment suppression is indicated by a *).  The first of these arguments is the same as for fscanf. That argument is immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type `rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument of the pair. (C111dr §K.3.5.3.2 6)

```
scanf_s("%c", &x, (rsize_t)1)
```

Other issues may exist.